# How do I conditionally include a file in place of another file with MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild

We have a project with a few different build configurations that have same-named files, but the contents are sometimes slightly different. Most of these files are in a **Resources** folder. Between MSBuild and Xamarin.Mac, the program knows to take the file out of the sub-folder matching the build configuration and move it up to the root of the **Resources** folder with the code below:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'ReleaseA'">
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\A\logo.png">
    <LogicalName>logo.png</LogicalName>
  </BundleResource>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'ReleaseB'">
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\B\logo.png">
    <LogicalName>logo.png</LogicalName>
  </BundleResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

So if I build `ReleaseA`, MSBuild knows that I want to treat `Resources\A\logo.png` as `Resources\logo.png`.

Now, I'm trying to accomplish the same thing with a single file not related to the Resources folder:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'ReleaseA'">
  <InterfaceDefinition Include="UI\A\FileSelectWindow.xib">
    <LogicalName>FileSelectWindow.xib<\LogicalName>
  </InterfaceDefinition>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'ReleaseB'">
  <InterfaceDefinition Include="UI\B\FileSelectWindow.xib">
    <LogicalName>FileSelectWindow.xib<\LogicalName>
  </InterfaceDefinition>
</ItemGroup>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and I'm not sure how to communicate to MSBuild that I want to treat the .xib file in sub-folder A or B as if it were actually `UI\FileSelectWindow.xib`

How do I go about doing this in MSBuild? I've tried custom commands, `<Move>`, and `<Copy>`, but they all actually modify the files that track in git. I've also tried having the files directly in the `UI` folder and naming them FileSelectWindow-A and FileSelectWindow-B with the same logical name to no avail either.